# How to compare values in Hastable?

Tags: java, hashtable

I want to compare values of Hashtable:

```
Hashset ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Hashset>();
for (Integer i: ht.keySet()) {
  for (Integer j: ht.keySet()){
           if(ht.get(i).contain(ht.get(j)))
           {
             //do something
           }
       }
 }
```

I used this code and i got the error `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` on the second loop. I want to check that the hashsets in my hashatable have same elements or not.
How can i do it?
Thanks.

Comment: @NiksTyagi How can i compare values in hashtable and merge them?

Comment: what do you mean by merge ?? Plz explain in detail frst

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is what you "do" inside your `if`.
*ConcurrentModification* means you are trying to change the `HashSet` while looping through the values by foreach. And that is not allowed

Perhaps you should think about using an `ArrayList` instead of an `Hashtable` (depends on the rest of your code ...)

In this case you could remember the "pairs" and do whatever you want to do with them later.